# How do I store JSON objects in indexedDB?

Tags: javascript, json, indexeddb

my return json file looks like this:

```
var data = [{"col1":"value1","col2":"value1","col3":"value1"},{"col1":"value2","col2":"value2","col3":"value2"},{"col1":"value3","col2":"value3","col3":"value3"}];
```

without JSON.stringify data looks like this:

[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]

but with it the result.length is not 5 but the total number of characters of the string and that way I cant do the loop

```
var result = JSON.stringify(data);
for(i=0; i<result.length; i++){
var transaction = db.transaction([STORE], IDBTransaction.READ_WRITE);
var put = transaction.objectStore(STORE).put(result);
};
```

Comment: Don't stringify and In line 4 put(result[i])

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
var data = [{"col1":"value1","col2":"value1","col3":"value1"},{"col1":"value2","col2":"value2","col3":"value2"},{"col1":"value3","col2":"value3","col3":"value3"}];
```

If you are trying to store each OBJECT, then don't stringify it or anything, it is already in perfect form. Change your `for()` loop to loop through the data objects.

**Kristof Degrave** had a good point to put these outside of the actual for loop for performance reasons.

```
    var transaction = db.transaction([STORE], IDBTransaction.READ_WRITE); 
    var objstore = transaction.objectStore(STORE); 

    for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) { 
        objstore.put(data[i]);
    }
```

Comment: Yes, working!!!
(I forgot to write the "[i]" in here) I was trying everything like: eval(), JSON.stringify() and JSON.parse() and didn't try it direct and with the loop...
Thanks a lot mcpDESIGNS! Cheers.

Comment: I would pull the transaction and the object store part outside the for loop, this will increase the performance.

Comment: hum... what do you mean Kristof? like calling an external function inside the loop to add each object? wouldn't that be even more circular?

Comment: Yeah it sounds like it needs each object inserted one at a time right?

Comment: Yes but do you think calling an outside function inside the loop every time an object needs to be "putted" will help increase performance? how?

Comment: Now you are creating a transaction and an objectstore object for every object you want to store. If you do this outside the for loop you will create it once and do the puts all in one transaction. Do it like this: var transaction = db.transaction([STORE], IDBTransaction.READ_WRITE); var objstore = transaction.objectStore(STORE); for(i = 0; i < data.length; i++){ objstore.put(data[i]); }

Comment: Good point! (as always)
Implemented it, ran a profile on it and it is faster, you wouldn't notice it for a small feed but I'm expecting it to process large amounts of data and in this case you will notice it.
Kristof, you're the man! Thanks

Comment: Putting the transaction and store outside of the for loop actually makes a huge difference for a large amount of data!

Answer (score 4):

For new visitors, suggesting a tad of modification:
IDBTransaction.READ_WRITE has been deprecated so use "readwrite" instead.

Resource: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IndexedDB_API/Using_IndexedDB
Reference:

> Older experimental implementations use the deprecated constant
>   IDBTransaction.READ_WRITE instead of "readwrite".

Also, to reduce the loc (which I mostly prefer), use:

```
var objstore = db.transaction([STORE], "readwrite").objectStore(STORE); 
for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) { 
    objstore.put(data[i]);
}
```